# How do you arrange your site-packages folder in python

Tags: python, python-module

I just downloaded django and installed it into `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`  So now my `site-packages` directory seems rather unorganized with 5 separate folders a bunch ot text files and a python script.  Should I create a sub directory in `site-packages` for the django package and store everything in there?  If I do that will the python intrepeter know to look in the `Django` directory in the `site-packages` directory for the django package?  Or will I have to change some environment variables around?

Thank you.

Comment: Did the distutils (setup.py) not work for you?

Comment: You should use `pip install` whenever you can. Also you can use `virtualenv` and do your tests in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking it because this is something you *need* to know because of some complex setting you have. In case you are just want to install Django, you should follow the install instructions from their [site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/?from=olddocs):

```
pip install Django
```

the directory order in site-packages is an internal mechanism of your Python build and I don't think you should change it, unless you want to create your own package and want to learn more on how python find installed packages (and if this is the case I would start reading this document: http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/index.html)

As suggested in the comments to your question, and also in the documentation of [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/?from=olddocs), you should consider using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/), especially when developing a webapp which will get deployed on a server with a specific Django version. Over time you'll see that you want to create other apps that require different versions of modules, and to still support the already existing apps you will need to use virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that, I got django to install just by extracting the files to the site-packages folder since I wasn't clear on how to work the terminal commands that great yet.  I have been working with them more so I think it would be good practice to go back and install django that way.  Do you use `pip install` in windows or can I use the git bash shell instead?

Comment: I just want to add one more thing because I got this to work and it installed perfectly; however on their website they say use the `sudo python setup.py install'` command to install and that didn't work so I just typed `python setup.py install` and that worked.  I just wanted to add that in case someone else in the future asks.